# Alternative of IN operator in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query in which IN operator is used but that query is very slow in production environment.

This is my query

```
SELECT col1 FROM table_name WHERE col2 IN (251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,
270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14) AND col3 > '1' AND col4 = 1 GROUP BY col1;
```

I tried find in set but still it is slow, I used composite indexing with the same order of columns as I wrote in where clause,  its query cost 151630.44, filter 100 and table contain million of records.

I am expecting to get its query cost as small as possible that is, 1 or 2 and filter  100.

Comment: What does the execution plan of that query tell you about the performance?

Comment: What version are you running?  There is a setting that may help.

Comment: I am using MYSQL 5.7.12 version

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and include the execution plan and the table structure

Answer (score 0):

In tends to be slower than comparison.  Seeing that your values appear to be largely sequential, try something like

```sql
SELECT col1 
FROM table_name 
WHERE ((col2 >=1 AND Col2 <=14) or (Col2 >=251 AND Col2 <=298)) 
AND col3 > '1' AND col4 = 1 
GROUP BY col1;
```